# Compilation error with boost::mpl::if_

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

I'm trying to control the constness of some pointer type based on the constness of some template parameter type using boost::mpl. Here's my attempt:

```
template<typename T>
struct iter {
   typedef typename boost::mpl::if_<boost::is_same<T, const list>, const sexpr *, sexpr *>::type pointer;
};
```

The compiler however rejects this saying:

```
sexpr.h:154: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `type name' with no type
sexpr.h:154: error: template argument 2 is invalid
sexpr.h:154: error: template argument 1 is invalid
sexpr.h:154: error: `type' does not name a type
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you don't have a semicolon after your struct if that helps any.

Comment: I missed this in the post, but I do have it in the code.

Comment: What is ```sexpr```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it using is_const:

```
typedef typename boost::mpl::if_<boost::is_const<T>, const sexpr *, sexpr *>::type pointer;
```

Thanks!